# How to resolve this error "ERROR: ld.so: object 'xxx' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored. "

Tags: shared-library, proxychains

To utilize the proxy on my Ubuntu system, I required the installation of proxychains. Here are the steps I took:

1. ```
   sudo apt-get install proxychains
   ```
2. ```
   sudo vim /etc/proxychains.conf
   ...
   [ProxyList]
   socks5 192.xxx.xxx.xxx 1080
   ```
3. ```
   sudo vim /usr/bin/proxychains
   ...
   #export LD_PRELOAD=libproxychains.so.3
   export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3
   ```

Then I run `proxychains curl www.google.com`, the proxy doesn't work but there's no error.
When I run `sudo proxychains curl www.google.com`, there's the error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

How can I fix this issue and run `proxychains` successfully? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3.0.0
```

this is the correct libraryname on Ubuntu (it reports "cannot open shared object file")

Comment: I agree, the required shared library is `libproxychains.so.3.0.0`. However, the `LD_PRELOAD` variable requires a `Link to shared library` type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by identifying a problem with my 'curl'. After reinstalling it, everything is running smoothly now.